# ArgumentOutOfRangeException error on clicking on empty area of DGV

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my searching form, now I have written code to generate *ContextMenuStrip* when ever I right click on a particular row and then it shows different options. Every thing works fine unless I click on the empty portion of the datagridview. It generates error

[image]

for more detail understanding consider the image below

[image]

It is all good when I press on the row but error comes when I click on the empty portion below this row

Here is code for the **MouseClickEvent**

```
 private void SearchPanelDataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip smenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
            var htest = SearchPanelDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            SearchPanelDataGridView.ClearSelection();

            SearchPanelDataGridView.Rows[htest.RowIndex].Selected = true;
            smenu.Items.Add("Clear Record").Name = "Clear Record";
            smenu.Items.Add("Pay Amount").Name = "Pay Amount";
            smenu.Items.Add("Break Apart").Name = "Break Apart";
            smenu.Items.Add("View Details").Name = "View Details";
            int CurrentMouseOverRow = SearchPanelDataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            smenu.Show(SearchPanelDataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            name = SearchPanelDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            cnic = SearchPanelDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            fathername = SearchPanelDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            City = SearchPanelDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();

            smenu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(smenu_ItemClicked);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? It should be quite easy to find exactly why it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method contains several places where this exception can occur.

---

The first place is the following line:

```
SearchPanelDataGridView.Rows[htest.RowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Your `htest.RowIndex` is `-1`, because you hit no row when you click within the empty space. You should check for the `-1` and leave.

The next place this exception can occur is accessing the `SearchPanelDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]` if no item is selected. So you should check the `Count` of the `SelectedRows` collection. and leave if it is `0`.

The exception can also occur when accessing the `Cells` via an index with is not within the range.

---

And don't forget the index starts with `0` and ends with `n-1` ;)

Comment: hi martin, you are right the error occurs at     SearchPanelDataGridView.Rows[htest.RowIndex].Selected = true;  and yes it is because of RowIndex is -1

Comment: I tried to Check RowIndex earlier but it didn't worked. Now I think I know what was the problem

Comment: It worked, I was just check rowindex > 0 Now I set it to htest.RowInde > -1 in if() , It works fine, Thank you :)